# Utilities.formatString() New Apps Script method, not working as intended

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am using the new method: Utilities.formatString()

In the [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_utilities#formatString) is says it is similar to sprintf %-style.

I searched and read [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) about sprintf in PHP.

I cannot seem to get this to work as intended. It is meant to pad this 8 character string with 4 leading zeros. I know there are other ways to do this, But I am trying to get a handle on this sprintf / formatString thing.

```
var noFormat = "12345678";
var formatted = Utilities.formatString("%012s", noFormat);
```

I expected the var formatted to be equal to "000012345678".
my debugger tell me that formatted = 0, or sometimes it throws an error..

I am confused.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try it like this :

```
function xxx(){
  var noFormat = '12345678'
  var formatted = Utilities.formatString("%012d", noFormat);
Logger.log(formatted)
}
```

the different parameters that can be used are easy to find on the web, [here is an example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) that explains how the argument must be evaluated in php but the usage is the same.

Logger result :

[image]

Comment: Thank you Serge, Worked like a charm, I guess I was confused about the Type Specifiers.
You Truly are a Jedi

Comment: Thanks ! I'll choose Yoda if I may... XD