# Use breaking line or new line command in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-editor

I make a script in which data send from google spreadsheet to WhatsApp in which I did not create a new line or did not support break line command. GAS does not support \n as well 
 statement for divide my message.

```
if(data[i][4]!="")
        {
        var tempDate=new Date(data[i][4])
        tempDate.setDate(tempDate.getDate() - 55);
        var message1 = 'Dear '+data[i][13]+' '+data[i][12]+' '+data[i] 
[11]+' '
        message1+= 'Thank you for choosing XXXX Holidays for your 
dream vacation, we are pleased to confirm your trip- '+data[i][3]+' 
departing on  '+Utilities.formatDate(data[i] 
[4],Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"dd-MMM-yyyy")+'.'
        message1+='Please submit your visa documents by 
'+Utilities.formatDate(tempDate,Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"dd-MMM- 
yyyy")+' to avoid delays in visa processing.'
        message1+='If there are any further queries, please be in touch 
with your sales representative- '+data[i][6]+' or you may call '+data[i] 
[5]+' office for further assistance. Our offices are open from 1100 to 1900 
hrs from Monday to Saturday.'
        message1+= 'Thanks & Kind regards,'
        message1+= 'Team XXX'
        }
```

This is current output:

Dear Mr ABC XYZ Thank you for choosing XXXX Holidays for your dream vacation, we are pleased to confirm your trip- South African Discovery departing on  12-May-2019. Please submit your visa documents by 18-Mar-2019 to avoid delays in visa processing.If there are any further queries, please be in touch with your sales representative- Thomas bond or you may call Mumbai office for further assistance. Our offices are open from 1100 to 1900 hrs from Monday to Saturday.Thanks & Regards XXX

Expected Output:

Dear Mr ABC XYZ

Thank you for choosing XXXX Holidays for your dream vacation, we are pleased to confirm your trip- South African Discovery departing on  12-May-2019.

Please submit your visa documents by 18-Mar-2019 to avoid delays in visa processing.If there are any further queries, please be in touch with your sales representative-Thomas bond or you may call MumbaiHO office for further assistance.

Our offices are open from 1100 to 1900 hrs from Monday to Saturday.

Thanks & Regards

XXX

Comment: A more fuller explanation: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15627298/utilities-formatstring-new-apps-script-method-not-working-as-intended]

Comment: @TheMaster did not work still using +'\\n'. if you want then I will send whole code with you and please help to solve this issue. and if any other alternative for this issue than also let me know.

Comment: Can you please share your email address or Skype address sir so i can share my whole code to solve my issue. @TheMaster

Comment: But here i didn't use HTML body because i call API from spreadsheet to send messages on WhatsApp business account. @TheMaster

Comment: @TheMaster issue solved. and solution for that is we have to encode the value of special character and then append with string.

Comment: @JAIMINVAGHANI how do you send to Whatsapp from Google Sheet?

Comment: `Logger.log('end of statement \n new line ')`

Answer (score 0):

The `\n` needed to be urlEncoded to `%0A` for the api to render it as new line.

```
 if(data[i][4]!="")
        {
            var tempDate=new Date(data[i][4])
        tempDate.setDate(tempDate.getDate() - 55);
        var message1 = 'Dear '+data[i][13]+' '+data[i][12]+' '+data[i][11]+' '
        message1+= '%0A%0AThank you for choosing XXXX Holidays for your dream vacation, we are pleased to confirm your trip- '+data[i][3]+' departing on  '+Utilities.formatDate(data[i][4],Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"dd-MMM-yyyy")+'.'
        message1+='%0A%0APlease submit your visa documents by '+Utilities.formatDate(tempDate,Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"dd-MMM-yyyy")+' to avoid delays in visa processing.'
        message1+='If there are any further queries, please be in touch with your sales representative- '+data[i][6]+' or you may call '+data[i][5]+' office for further assistance. %0A%0AOur offices are open from 1100 to 1900 hrs from Monday to Saturday.'
        message1+= '%0A%0AThanks %26 Kind regards,'
        message1+= '%0A%0ATeam XXX '
        }
```